# Linux file utility magic.mgc database get content

Tags: linux, file, unix

I write project where I need to identify certain file formats.
For some formats I have found signatures that I use for identifying easily (mp3, ogg), with another formats  I have a big problem (like MPEG ADTS) - I just cannot find what kind of signature can be used for it.

I found out that File  utility for Linux environment can do it. 
I tried to search it in source code, but I've found nothing.

I found that file utility holds its database in magic.mgc file. But it's hold in binary form.
It looks like:
[image]

Does someone perhaps know how to find that database in plain text format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That utility isn't a Linux-specific utility; it's [the version of the UN*X file command originally written by Ian Darwin](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/).  The binary `.mgc` file is generated from a bunch of source files.

Your Linux distribution probably has a source code package for it; where you get that package, and how you install it, depends on which distribution you're using.

The source files from which the `.mgc` file was generated might also be available on your distribution *without* installing the source package for `file`; if so, you could use the `file` command to generate it, using the `-C` flag.  I don't see them anywhere obvious on my Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine, so that might require some *other* package to be installed (`file` itself *is* installed).  (On OS X, they're in the directory `/usr/share/file/magic`.)

Alternatively, you could download the standard version of that file (which might have been modified by your distribution, so you might not want that version) and modify and build it.

Note that, on some versions of UN*X systems, the bulk of the work done by the `file` command is done in library routines in the "libmagic" library; see whether your distribution has that or can install it (try, for example, `man libmagic`) and whether it can do the job for you.

Comment: it would be nice if I could find this information in the source code, but I have watched through all code and I've nothing found (although it should be there, but  I really dont't see it!)

Comment: Look in the `magic` subdirectory of the source code directory.

Comment: okay, thanks, I found something in that place - http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/13/0202/h_1359811651_3068937_b0f804756a.png . As I understand this is the categories of files' formats. But if I open one, meaning of content is not understandable   http://codepad.org/NwXA6YPx   , I expected to find there something like "mp3 format - has such header", "mp4  - has such header" and so on, but what is it?  Thanks, for you attempt to make things clear

Comment: Those files are primarily for computers (in particular, for the `file` command) to read; they support comments as aids to humans, but there's no guarantee that the writer of a portion of the magic file will bother to add comments.  `man magic` should describe the format of the file on your system.

Comment: For MPEG ADTS, the file you want to look at is, somewhat obscurely, named "animation".  [MPEG ADTS has no "magic number"](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS); the "animation" file does a hack based on the syncword, version, and layer fields, as well as the data rate.  See the comments in that file.